# R Quantmod International Yahoo Finance SSL Certificate Obstacle

Tags: r, ssl, quantmod, yahoo-finance, stock

After trial and error, I continue to see one error using the Quantmod package. I can download exogenous info from Google and FRED on Japanese stocks and USA economic data, but I cannot retrieve any data from yahoo finance for Japanese stocks. Is there any alternatives to retrieving data from international stock markets other than yahoo? Also, I don't think I can change any permissions for SSLs outside of RStudio, because I am working on a multi-user server. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
MU <- getSymbols("MU",src="google", auto.assign=FALSE) #Correct
getSymbols("PCU334413334413A",src="FRED", from='2013-01-02', to = '2017-11-06')
[1] "PCU334413334413A"
SKH <- getSymbols('000660.ks',src='yahoo', auto.assign=FALSE) #Correct
Error in curl::curl_download(cu, tmp, handle = h) : SSL connect error
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search and stumbled upon this.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols.yahooj("3048.T", verbose=TRUE, auto.assign=TRUE)
```

I know Yahoo turned off their finance API back in May.  Now, it doesn't seem like there is a whole lot out there.  At least not for free.

http://stocks.finance.yahoo.co.jp/stocks/history/?code=6758.T

Comment: Thanks, your stock symbol is correct, however this issue pertains to SSL certificates